# Why does this loop print out the bottom line 3 times?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;

    public class AmusementPark {
    private ArrayList<Ticket> tickets;
    private ArrayList<Merchandise> merchandise;
    private String name;
    AmusementPark(String name){
        this.name=name;
        this.tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
        this.merchandise= new ArrayList<Merchandise>();
    }
    void addTicket(long num, String cat, String h, String dt, double pr, boolean pch){
        Ticket test = new Ticket(num, cat, h, dt, pr, pch);
        tickets.add(test);
    }

    String getName(){
        return name;



    }
    public ArrayList<String> getTicketDates(){
           ArrayList<String> theDateArray= new ArrayList<>();
           int i;

           for (i=0; i <tickets.size(); i++){
               if(tickets .get(i).getPurchased()== false){
                 theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate());
               }
             }
             for(int f=0; f<theDateArray.size();f++){
               System.out.println(theDateArray.get(f)+ " ");
             }
             return theDateArray;
           }       



     public int getTickets(String date){
         int tix= getTicketDates().indexOf(date);
         int occurances= Collections.frequency(getTicketDates(), tix);
         if (tix>=0){
             System.out.println(occurances);


         }
         return occurances;
     }
    }
```

Now, here is the main class....

```
public class AmusementParkTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    AmusementPark park1= new AmusementPark("Walden University Park");

    park1.addTicket(777, "Child", "Noah Johnson","2017-06-09" , 27.99, false);

    System.out.println("The dates in which tickets are available are as follows: ");
            park1.getTicketDates();

            park1.getTickets("2017-06-09");

    }



}
```

If I add and item to the tickets ArrayList, and then I print out the method getDate, it prints out the date 3 times.  I tried everything including taking the print statement out and putting it outside the next }.  When I put in a break, it gives me a dead code error.

What this loop is basically doing is taking another list called tickets, and when the boolean of the getDate method is false, it adds the date in the form of a String to the next ArrayList.  The dates are printing 3 times for each ticket though.

***UPDATE***

I added the entire class as well as the main class to it.

The getTickets method is where a date is searched, and the amount of tickets in the ArrayList that meet that date is returned as an integer.

Once I call that method on the main class, it repeats the date 3 times, and it still doesn't return the right integer in the next method.

Comment: Your code would be much clearer using enhanced for loops.

Comment: And what does `tickets` contain?

Comment: `if(tickets.get(i).getPurchased()== false);` ... what is that semicolon doing there?

Comment: You have a extra `;` before the if block. This is changing you code semantics!

Comment: remove the internal for loop out of the external one...

Comment: I explained in an edit what the loop is trying to do.

Comment: I deleted the semi colon.  It wasn't initially there.  I was playing around with it and added it, and forgot to delete it when it didn't help.

Comment: The loop inside a loop might do it.

Comment: I took out the loop inside the loop and tried the code every person gave.  It still does the same thing.

Comment: Okay, I edited the code exactly as it is, and I included the entire class as well as the main method.  

This problem only happens when I add the getTickets method to the main method, so the problem is somewhere in that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is commonly the case, good indentation makes the problem clearer.

Because the loop with the `System.out.println` is inside the other loop, you print out the contents of `theDateArray` multiple times.

Assuming all of the tickets in `tickets` aren't purchased, you add a new element to `theDateArray` each time; so:

1. On the first iteration you print 1 element
2. On the second iteration you print 1 + 1 elements
3. On the third iteration you print 1 + 1 + 1 elements
   ...

Move this loop outside the other loop:

```
for (i=0; i <tickets.size(); i++){
  if(tickets .get(i).getPurchased()== false){
    theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate());
  }
}
for(int f=0; f<theDateArray.size();f++){
  System.out.println(theDateArray.get(f)+ " ");
}
```

Also, note that enhanced for loops make this much cleaner:

```
for (Ticket t : tickets) {
  if (!t.getPurchased()) {
    theDateArray.add(t.getDate());
  }
}
for (String date : theDateArray) {
  System.out.println(date + " ");
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code over mine.  It's still doing the exact same thing.

Comment: im wondering about your claim "If I add an item to the tickets ArrayList",
are you positively sure that the ticket arraylist actually has only One item?
maybe add the code showing where you create the arrayList and add the ticket to it

Comment: I only have one item in the arrayList.  It prints the date out 3 times.

Comment: See **Update***

Comment: I only have 1 item in the ArrayList as you can see.  When I don't include the getTickets method, it is just fine.  When I call that method to the main method in the Tester class, it repeats it 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong int inside second loop, instead of int i you should use int f. Like someone else mentioned in the comments you have to many brackets, remove one after if and another before return and it should be ok. Try this code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getTicketDates(){
   ArrayList<String> theDateArray= new ArrayList<>();
   int i;

   for (i=0; i<tickets.size(); i++){
      if(tickets.get(i).getPurchased()== false)
         theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate());
   }

   for(int f=0; f<theDateArray.size();f++){
      System.out.println(theDateArray.get(f)+ " ");
   }       

   return theDateArray;
}
```

Comment: That's good to know.  I fixed it, but it still is doing the same thing.

Comment: See **Update***

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<tickets.size(); i++){
            if(tickets.get(i).getPurchased()== false);{
                theDateArray.add(tickets.get(i).getDate());
            }
            for(int f=0; f<theDateArray.size();f++){
                System.out.println(theDateArray.get(i)+ " ");

            }

        }return theDateArray;
```

There is a semicolon after `if(tickets.get(i).getPurchased()== false);` inside the for loop, this makes it a body-less if, and the block of code following will always be executed . May be your input data data is such that the loop runs 3 times, thus the output

Comment: That was fixed.